# Proper solution to "No such file stdarg.h" error

Tags: drivers, arch-linux, compile, make

When I try to compile an [rtl8723au wifi driver for my laptop](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au) but I keep on getting the following error:

```
./include/linux/kernel.h:6:10: fatal error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
```

My current solution is to add directory to compiler includes path like this:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.1.0/include/
```

But it is very bad solution, because I have to change compiler version (`8.1.0` in above example) after each time when compiler updates. What is proper solution to this problem?

Comment: @JakeGould in fact I discover this solution [by myself](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au/issues/68), but before asking this question I found that issue with same (not ideal) solution, so I decide to ask question